Is it possible to optionally match paired quotations marks (before and after a string)?
I'm trying to make a substitution in a file with a one liner regex. sed failed me so I turned to perl. I can for example match "setting = value # comment" and extract it in three parts "setting = ", "value" and " # comment".
For example:
perl -lne 'print "-1-$1-2-$2-3-$3-E-" if /^\s*(setting\s*=\s*)([^\s#]+)(\s*#\s*.*)?/'

and I'll see a result like -1-setting = -2-value-3- # comment-E-
Now the problem emerges that value might be wrapped in quotes, whether single or double, the simple ' or '" character. Unbiased, same in the opening and closing form.
It's tempting to use a backreference to detect matching quotes:
perl -lne 'print "-1-$1-2-$2-3-$3-4-$4-5-$5-E-" if /^\s*(setting\s*=\s*)(\N{APOSTROPHE}|\N{QUOTATION MARK})?([^\s#]+)(\2)?(\s*#\s*.*)?/'

The problem here is that group 3 captures the closing quotation and group 4 is empty.
And here we run into a problem. We cannot add the backreference to the negative assertion for group 3, perl doesn't support that for the simple reason that the capture group is not a character (or not guranteed to be one, even though ours is).
So this raises a conundrum. Is there a way to catch these optional matching quotes in a perl regex?
My thinking and reading and experimentation thus far led me to consider the possibility of:

A negative assertion on strings not characters. We have [abc] which matches a, b or c, and we have [^abc] matching any charcater that is not a, b or c, and we have (string1|string2|string3) which matches any of string1, string2, or string3. But is there a negative form of that assertion, any strig that is not string1, string2, or string3?

Creating a character group, a capture group of one character that can be used in a backreference in a negative character set?

Referencing one character in a backreference, like the first character.

Referring to a backreference as a set of characters not a string ... for inclusion in the negative set.

Using a look around assertion. Alas, we have look behind and look ahead but not look at.


Maybe this is too hard for a regex?

Can you show some examples? It's unclear whether a value can contains whitespace, inside or outside of quotes. Also, I guess # is valid inside quotes.

instead of making the quotation group optional with the ? quantifier, add an empty alternative at the end of the group. Other way: rewrite your pattern using a branch reset group.

Indeed. Some examples (apocryphal) file = '/somedir/some file.someextension' # Configure the file, or name = joe or count=55#configure the counter or fullname="my full name"   # Yep that's it. All those are legal and sort of expected variants.

Oooh, "branch reset group" is a new term to me. Do tell, and maybe provide an example of such a rewrite?

Oh and yes I imagine inside of quotes most any printable char is allowed.

You can use the following:
^
\s*
( setting \s* = \s* )
( ' [^'\\]* '           # I'm assuming `\` has a special meaning. Remove the `\` if not.
| " [^"\\]* "           # I'm assuming `\` has a special meaning. Remove the `\` if not.
| [^'"#\s]+             # `\w+` might be better.
)
( \s* \# .* )?

A + can be appended to every *, + and ? to speed up failed matches.

Sure it is possible, but how exactly to do it (and how complicated it may turn out) depends on what data -- between the possible quotes in the first place -- need be parsed and that is not stated.
With the pattern used in the question, [^\s#]+ (no spaces or #), and assuming that there shall be no embedded quotes in data (reasonable but a constraint), one can use for quotes a normal (optional) capture and then an (optional) relative backreference
/^\s*(\w+\s*=\s*) (['"])? ([^\s#]+) \g{-2}? \s*(\#.*)?/x

It doesn't matter that some capture groups are undef, as you need to count them anyway.  Here the (relative) backreference \g{-2} conveniently refers to the second previous capture.   The setting word in the question seems to be an example so I use \w for it.  Replace as suitable.
So the "setting" is in $1, then $2 has a quote or is undef if there are no quotes, the "value" is in $3 and the comment in $4 (which is undef if there is no comment).
Or, use named captures for things you want, which then makes counting irrelevant
/^\s*(?<set>\w+\s*=\s*) (['"])? (?<val>[^\s#]+) \g{-2}? \s*(?<cmt>\#.*)?/x

After the regex the named captures are in %+, so $+{set} etc.
Or, can use a named capture group for what you don't need (the quotes), for easier reference
/^\s*(\w+\s*=\s*) (?<q>['"])? ([^\s#]+) \g{q}? \s*(\#.*)?/x

(q for "quotes")    The dollar variables still count with named captures so the captured "value" is still in $3 in this example and the comment in $4 (if there is a comment).
A comment by the poster says:

The use case is a bash script that wants to update a configured value in a configuration file.  Which has the general format of support # comments and a setting = value syntax where value can be a number, a string containing no spaces or a quoted string.

I assume that a "quoted string" implies that there are no quotes in the string but if escaped quotes are allowed please state that.
All these variations print what is expected in my tests, with various input.  They cover all cases I came up with, with a reasonable requirement that there be no quotes in the "value."

It's not stated in the question what exactly need be captured inside quotes, or without them.
It seems reasonable that spaces may be allowed in a quoted string (also mentioned in a poster's comment). This is opposite to the pattern in the question and the poster's explicit comment but if it is so then just remove that \s from your negated character class.
With the quotes a hash mark (#) can be allowed, but with no quotes it can't if a following comment is allowed.  This is possible to include but it makes the regex more complex.
How about embedded quotes?  A pattern can disallow them but then we'd have to break the pattern up into an alternation of cases, one for ' and the other for ", what ikegami's answer does.  If escaped quotes are to be allowed then this gets yet a bit more complicated.
In the end, the question is of how general this parsing needs to be.  Clearly not very, if a single-statement regex in a one-liner is wanted.  Then just trim it to what is reasonable.
Or please specify details about data and requirements.

That forbids "abc def", which seems like a problem

@ikegami "That forbids "abc def""  -- you mean as the (possibly) quoted thing to capture?  I decided to use \w as a place holder of sorts for simplicity, as commented in text, since that wasn't disputed/asked about.  They can replace what they need.

No they can't. Changing the \w+ to allow spaces and # would allow abc def and abc # def which do not appear to be allowed. But not changing to allow those would forbid "abc def" and "abc # def", which seems wrong.

@ikegami "Changing the \w+ to allow spaces and # ... -- They specifically disallow these (with [^\s#]+) ...?  But either way, they can replace my \w+ with [^\s#]+ to have what they wrote in the question, but now with optional quotes.  (I could've just left their [^\s#]+ instead of \w+ and I considered it.)  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you are saying?

@ikegami  How does this discussion relate to the issue of quotes, what they are asking?  The pattern to be captured is an open issue, I absolutely agree (which is precisely why I use a "place holder" \w+ for it), but they aren't asking that and it doesn't affect the quotes.  Am I missing something?

\w may be an option, except that problem is the quoted string would be quoted specifically because it can contain non w characters include spaces, special characters like !@_ or even # - it is a quoted string for a reason, to allow a parser to recognise it as that. I was aiming to match not (\w+)so much(anything except the matching quote)` which is itself only a partial implementation as the string could conceivably include escaped quotes .... but hey. Which is why I'm thinking a regex may be stretched beyond its capability here.

The use case is a bash script that wants to update a configured value in a configuration file. Which has the general format of support # comments and a setting = value syntax where value can be a number, a string containing no spaces or a quoted string.

Re "They specifically disallow these", Outside of quotes, yes. That's the problem. The prevents them from being allowed in quotes. /// Re "How does this discussion relate to the issue of quotes, what they are asking?", Your approach can't match setting foo = "abc def" without matching setting foo = abc def. It doesn't work. That's the whole point of allowing quotes.

@BerndWechner "can contain non characters include spaces ..."  -- No, your regex has ([^\s#]+) inside the (optional quotes).  No spaces.  You asked about quotes, not how to write a pattern for what's in between them.  You don't even explain what should be in between them.  Just replace my \w+ for your ([^\s#]+) and off you go.  Now if this comment is a clarficiation of the question then I can edit my answer....

@BerndWechner Rewrote the answer.  Given your comment, "general format of support # comments and a setting = value syntax where value can be a number, a string containing no spaces or a quoted string, your [^\s#]+ is good enough and variations in this answer satisfy the specs -- with an additional constraint that the value has no quotes in it (no escaped ones either).

@BerndWechner  If anything special may be in that "quoted string" -- like escaped quotes, then the pattern need be changed.  Note, you may allow spaces even if the string isn't quoted (the # is a marker, or end of string) -- unless you want to support trailing text as well, like setting = value  follow-on-irrelevant-text

@ikegami Rewrote the answer.  Thanks for comments

@BerndWechner Edited for clarity
